# Match only a specific tag

Tags: html, css, regex

I need to find only the empty `<i>` tags which may or may not have attributes.

This matches `<i>` but also `<img>` and `<input>`:

```
<i[^>]*[^>]*></[^>]*>
```

How do I match only `<i>` tags?

Comment: You want to match `<i>` only or `<i></i>`

Comment: @Reddy The whole `<i class="someclass"></i>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change the last part of regex to `</i>` right. This way it will not end up selecting input and img

`<i[^>]*[^>]*></i>`

EDIT:
Version to catch and include any whitespace between the *`<i>`* tags. Also does **not** capture other tags such as `<img>`:

```
<i(?:\h|)+[^>]*>(\h+)*<\/i>
```

Will catch `<i> </i>` or `<i></i>`. 
Will not catch `<img>`.
(Also escaped the final slash)

Comment: Fine answer - except it doesn't ensure that the opening and closing tag are the same, e.g. will match `<img></i>`. Also missing the escape on the backslash.

Comment: I saw that re:backslash but at the risk of causing confusion I decided to not add it as this would be in consistent with Reddy's original answer. @Utkanos

Comment: @Utkanos yes I knew it too.. but assuming the HTML is properly structured this must work. Also since this will match other tags in the beginning I think it's bit low in performance compared to yours. I am on mobile so can't do much with testing and answering ..

Comment: I have updated my edit to exclude `<img>` and other non-i tags. Sorry for taking over your answer, Reddy. @3zzy

Comment: @Martin Thank you for doing that part. You are awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<i( [^>]+)?><\/i>
```

The space ensures only `i` tags are matched, not other tags beginning with 'i'.

Comment: I didn't realise the OP meant capturing invalid HTML - the question suggested a closing tag was present too.

Comment: I am not the OP :p ... I edited my previous comment as I realized the ? and that must just do it

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS [:empty pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty). For example:

```
i:empty {
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```css
i:empty {
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<i class="someclass"></i>

<i></i>

<i class="someclass">not empty</i>

<i>not empty</i>
```

Comment: @Martin no because that's invalid HTML.

Comment: I'm doing a find/replace so it has to be regex, but good to know about `:empty`

Comment: Not relevant for the question but yes definitely good to know about `:empty`